# Different results with same inputs but different ways of inputting

Tags: c, opencv, labview

I have an external function from an opencv dll, cvCreateFileCapture, that should take the path as an input and return a structure.

`CV_IMPL CvCapture * cvCreateFileCapture (const char * filename)`

I created a vs2010 project for testing purposes from where i call this function with a valid file path and get the structure i was supposed to get returned.

When I call this function from a different program (I'm using labVIEW) I jump into the same function with the same input but it returns 0.

Does anyone have an idea why it works 1 way but not the other?

The C call is `CvCapture* p = cvCreateFileCapture("C:/Users/****/Downloads/Disturbedloc.avi");`

the labview call looks like this:

[image]

Comment: If the same function is returning a different value for the same inputs then the function is incorrectly written. However I suspect that the "same function" is actually the incorrect assumption.

Comment: Are you sure you used double backslashes "\\" or "/" in your name? Also, why are you using obsolete C syntax?

Comment: Im running the debug and it goes through the same function, so im pretty sure it is indeed the same function. The input for both is C:/Users/Username/Downloads/Disturbedloc.avi. Its easier to use the C sytax in LabVIEW.

Comment: The returned value (0) is the one you see in LabVIEW or the one sent from the called funcion? Can you post a code snippet of the LabVIEW code and tell us details on how you call the OpenCV function ?

Comment: @MisterEmme both and yes i will do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Load time debugging

If the library call works in one environment but not another, then there's a difference in the environment. There are two main approaches:

1. Use [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to make sure that `opencv` has the correct linkage. Perhaps Visual Studio is inspecting `opencv` for other libraries ([like FFMPEG or GStreamer](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/d02627ea89b3606cc75ae39af79c3a562be947ac/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp#L272)) and [adding extra loader instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to fetch those binaries on launch. LabVIEW, on the other hand, will do a [pure dynamic load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and if the library doesn't correctly advertise its dependencies, then those libraries won't be loaded and you'll get a `NULL` pointer.
2. Attach Visual Studio to LabVIEW before your VI makes the first call into `opencv` then watch the [Modules window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290851%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to see if the support libraries are resident in memory. Comparing against your working Visual Studio program would show if any are missing.

### Loading missing libraries by force

That run-time linking doesn't work in `opencv` is a bug in their project. You should report that to them.

You have two workarounds:

1. Fix the bug, build `opencv` yourself, and redistribute it with your application.
2. Call [dummy entry points](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/77594203D78D12278625729100758BE5) in each dependency to prompt LabVIEW to bring them into the process. Then start calling into `opencv`.

### Once it's working

Since your `opencv` dll returns a pointer to a struct, you have two options:

1. Wrap and adapt the `opencv` library in another C/C++ library so that the inputs/outputs are simpler data types, like numerics.
2. Use a cluster and some specific Call Library Function node configuration so that LabVIEW can understand the memory layout of the `opencv` types. NI has a some good documents describing how LabVIEW interfaces with external libraries, but start here: [Calling C/C++ DLLs from LabVIEW](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-9076).

Comment: Since it returns a pointer i should be able to see it in labview, it works with all other pointers to structs. The problem is that this pointer is 0 when it should not be.

Comment: I added a few ways to explore the initial conditions.

Comment: You are right, the ffmpeg dll only loads for vs. A bit of followup, how can i link the ffmpeg dll to the videoio dll? If it were a lib i would know, but a lib is not createdfor ffmpeg

Comment: I added a new section for force-loading libraries.

Comment: the runtime linking works for the vs approach just not for labview. I found a temporary workaround though by jus empty calling a function from ffmpeg the dll is loaded. The problem isnt fixed yet, but i know what is wrong now which was the biggest step so ill give you the solution already

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried and it is working for me.

Here is the front panel:

[image]

And the block diagram:

[image]

I'm using Labview 2014 and OpenCV 3.0.

I had problems (i.e. 0 returned) with more complex Paths (including spaces, etc.)

Comment: im using the videoio dll, not the world